# Does AWS IVS support multi-host live streaming?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ivs

I have gone through AWS document and its seems I am not being able to figure out whether AWS IVS supports multi-host?

Comment: What is your definition of "multi-host"?

Answer (score 0):

The stream sent to Amazon Interactive Video Service (IVS) **must come from one location**.

However, you could mix multiple video feeds into that stream *before* sending it to IVS. This is commonly done with online services like [StreamYard](https://streamyard.com/) or manually mixed via [Streamlabs OBS](https://streamlabs.com/) and [VDO.Ninja](https://docs.vdo.ninja/).

Comment: Thanks John for your help. 
Just one thing I want to know is there any open source alternative in node js that provide such bvideo mixing?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at Multiple Hosts feature launched with Amazon IVS that may be useful - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/media/add-multiple-hosts-to-live-streams-with-amazon-ivs/